# linux kernel forked child return of status

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, kernel

So here's my dilemma: Why when I `fork();` a child of a process and it ends,  the returned `&status` of the child is shifted to the left by 8 bit?

For example let's say i have `exit(4);` at the end of the forked child , my status in the `wait(&status);`
of the father process gets me `0x400`.

so here is some code that illustrates what I mean

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  int n, status, cpid;

  printf("Parent pid = %d\n",  getpid());

  n = fork();

  if (n != 0) {
     //  parent code
     printf ("I'm the parent with PID %d \t fork returned %d \t my parent is %d\n", getpid(), n, getppid()); 
     status = 0;
     sleep(5);      // verify status of child
     cpid = wait(&status);

     // so when i printf the hex value of status it gets shifted 
     printf("I received from my child %d this information %x\n", cpid, status);

   } else {
        // child code
        printf ("I'm the child with PID %d \t fork returned %d \t my parent is %d\n", getpid(), n, getppid());
        sleep(20);
        printf("Child complete\n");
        status=12345;

        // the line that returns the shifted value
        exit(4);
     }

     printf("Parent complete\n");
     exit(15);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `status` hold not only the return code of the child bu it holds another information.
if you want to know the exit value you have to use the `WEXITSTATUS` macro

from wait manual:

> WEXITSTATUS(status)
>   returns the exit status of the  child.   This  consists  of  the
>                 **least  significant  8 bits of the status argument** that the child
>                 specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or  as  the  argument
>                 for  a  return  statement  in main().  This macro should only be
>                 employed if WIFEXITED returned true.

that's mean that the `status` integer holds another information and to extract this information you should use the macros which defined in `sys/wait.h`

Answer (score 6):

Read the documentation on [`wait(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wait).  The value returned is a 32-bit integer containing the exit status (if the process exited normally), as well as a number of flag bits.  To determine if the process exited normally, use the `WIFEXITED()` macro.  If that returns true, then use the `WEXITSTATUS()` macro to get the actual exit status:

```
int status;
if(wait(&status) > 0)
{
    // Did the process exit normally?
    if(WIFEXITED(status))
    {
        // This is the value you really want
        int actual_status = WEXITSTATUS(status);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: well yes, I understand but if you print that value into hex it's shifted by 8 bits (look in the printf where I use %x)

Comment: @Lucian: Yes, what's your point?  That's an implementation detail.

Comment: @LucianEnache: That's just how `wait()` returns it (on your implementation) - the `WEXITSTATUS()` macro will shift it back.